# Not sure of type of auto

Tags: c++

This code

```
template<typename T>
pair<T,T> f1 (vector<T> &v){
    T result1 = v[0];
    T result2 = v[0];
    for(auto itr=v.begin(); itr<v.end(); itr++){
    if (*itr > result1)
        result1 = *itr;
    if (*itr < result2)
        result2 = *itr;
    }
    return make_pair(result1, result2);
}

vector<string> v_s = {"hi", "mom", "how", "are", "you", "today"};
auto res1 = f1(v_s);       // Line 1
```

Why is the type of res1 not pair T, T?

And what would it be? Would it be Pair String, String

Comment: Try `static_assert(is_same<decltype(res1), pair<string, string>>, "No pair");` after the last line. Be sure to include `<type_traits>`.

Comment: Ah, this is a question on a practice exam and I just wasn't sure what the correct answer would be(the answer is none of the above)  One of the options is pairT,T but I guess the correct answer would be pair string, string .. would just like some clarification

Comment: Whenever not sure, you can always write a [code like this](http://ideone.com/IExF9D), compile and run to verify the types.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it would be `std::pair<std::string, std::string>`

Type of v_s is `std::vector<std::string>`, so the type deduced for T is `std::string` causing the return type to become `std::pair<std::string, std::string>`.

Type of res1 not `pair<T, T>` because `T` is a templated type and compiler generates actual function from template as required.

**About auto keyword**
`auto` ([c++11](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b11) onwards) specifies that the type of the variable that is being declared will be automatically deduced from its initializer. [c++14](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b14) onwards you can use `auto` also as function return type.

Answer (score 1):

The type of `res1` is the return type of `f1(v_s)` which we know to be `pair<T, T>`. We also know `T` is `string` because it was deduced by the type of the vector.